# Notation in Old Paper

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

I am reading a paper

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-04/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5.pdf

and I am wondering about the notation in the lemma page which states that

"...there exist a value $n_o$ of n and a sub-interval $[\alpha_0, \beta_0]$ such that $H_{n_0}$ is dense in $H • [\alpha_0, \beta_0]$.

Specifically, what does $H • [\alpha_0, \beta_0]$ mean?

Comment: multiplication used to be used to denote intersection (and + to denote union). Just a guess.

Comment: As the summation seems to stand for union (i.e. $H=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty H_n$), it appears that multiplication statnds for intersection (i.e. $H\cap [\alpha_0,\beta_0]$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the intersection of two sets. Some authors (in old papers, indeed) use $A+B$ for $A\cup B$ and $A\cdot B$ for $A\cap B$. It makes sense when you think of Boolean algebras.